# Missing icons in context menu in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, unity

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 and was wondering why no icons are shown in the context menu. Here an example if I right click on the desktop.

[image]

Can I somehow enable the icons to be shown? Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[UPDATE]
Sometimes the method below does not work (or maybe never?)

However I managed to enable/disable menu icons with **gnome-tweak-tool** under "Theme".

[/UPDATE]

You need to install dconf-tools first

```
sudo apt-get install dconf-tools
```

Then you can run dconf-editor from terminal

```
sudo dconf-editor
```

Now navigate to org.gnome.desktop.interface and look out for

```
menus-have-icons
```

and activate the checkbox. You are good to go now.

Additionally you might want to activate icons on Buttons, too. Its in the same settings container:

```
buttons-have-icons
```

same procedure as with menus-have-icons, just activate the checkbox and you are good to go.

Good Luck and have Fun!

Comment: In addition, I installed `gnome-tweak-tool` and activated both points under `Theme`. I found this information here http://blog.coffeebeans.at/?p=274. Thank you!

Comment: odd, normally they should instantly be displayed.

I checked with my laptop and was able to enable/disable them with gnome-tweak-tool. I update the answer...

Comment: Perfect, thx for the vote, although I do not really earned it ;)